# Pyserial readline() shows mix up of bits

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, x3d, falcon

I am very new to Arduino and Python. I'm working on the communication between an Arduino Uno and my laptop using Pyserial. The Python script in my laptop is called by an H3D Viewer, which is linked to a Novint Falcon.

My laptop sends the positional data of the Falcon to the Arduino, to be sent to the robot. Right now I'm merely trying to read back the data I sent from the Arduino, to make sure everything works. But it doesn't!

Here is part of my Python script (which is called by a .x3d file).

```
dp_text, = references.getValue()

class display (threading.Thread): 
  def __init__(self, delay):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.delay = delay

  def run(self):
    while 1:

        receivedFalconData=[]
        tex=[]
        tex.append("DevicePosX = " + str(localFalconData))

        receivedFalconData=ser.readline()
        ser.flush()
        ser.flushInput()
        tex.append("Input = " + str(receivedFalconData))

        dp_text.string.setValue(tex)
        time.sleep(self.delay)

displaying = display(0.1)
displaying.start()
```

The above thread is in charged of refreshing the text node in the H3D Viewer every 100ms. The Arduino's code is below:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

char Axispos[6] ={0,0,0,0,0,0};
int xvalue= 0;

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7,6); //RX, TX

void setup() {

  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  Serial.flush();
  mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  while( Serial.available() > 0 ) 
  {
    Serial.readBytes(Axispos,6);
    Serial.flush();

    xvalue = (Axispos[0] << 8) + (Axispos[1] & 0xff);

    Serial.println(xvalue);
    Serial.flush();

    mySerial.write(Axispos);
    mySerial.flush();

    delay(500);

  }
}
```

The x-axis value read by the Arduino is sent back to the laptop and stored in receivedFalconData. This value is supposed to be the same as localFalconData, which is the x-axis value in the script itself.

The results: receivedFalconData mimics localFalconData for a few seconds, before going wild.

It sometimes shows the correct value again, though, which tells me this is probably an issue with the Pyserial input buffer overflow? How could this be the case, since (if I'm correct) serial.readline() empties the input buffer after reading it? Furthermore, the Arduino only sends data every .5 second, whereas the laptop reads every .1 second.

But when the readline() part is placed in the class for sending data (which is called whenever the Falcon has new data available), receivedFalconData is perfectly correct.

Also, I get two of these ☐ symbols behind receivedFalconData when it is displayed in H3D...

Can someone who has experience with Pyserial please please help me? I would gladly give more info if my problem is still unclear to you.

Comment: Please not that `readline` will read the serial port until an end of line character is received (by default `\n`). If your data has any new lines, they will be misinterpreted as the eol character.

Comment: Also I don't think you can write `mySerial.write(Axispos)`. You should loop the array and write each value separately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

In my Arduino code, there's only one println() instruction. Doesn't that mean that my laptop simply constantly reads xvalue \n xvalue \n xvalue\n ...... ?

Comment: I tried sending constant dummy data from my computer: 

data = [3,6,9,12,15,18]
ser.write(data)

The data I got back was 774, which is correct (3 is the highbyte, 6 is the lowbyte, hence 1100000110b = 774). But again, the same behaviour. It shows 774 for a few seconds, then goes bonkers..